# Accessing this in anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I want to create a `prototype` function that has its own scope. For this, I use an anonymous function but I cannot find a way to access the members of the object.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
function F() {
    this.counter = 0;
} 

F.prototype.increment = (function() {
    var lastIncrementTime = -1;
    var caller = this; // <--- it fails here because this is the Window object
    return function(time) {
        if (time > lastIncrementTime) {
            caller.counter++;
            lastIncrementTime = time;
            return caller.counter;
        }
        return caller.counter;
    }
})();

f = new F();

f.increment();
```

I know it fails because this does not refer to `F` or the `f` object.

Is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)* itself only gets invoked once, all calls to `increment` will use the variables as they were last left and not re-`var` them.

Change the invocation context using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
F.prototype.increment = (function() {
    // this === F.prototype
    // ...
}).call(F.prototype);
```

The `this` in this example context will not be instance specific, but be the prototype.

---

It seems like you actually want to achieve something a little bit different, where you have an independent *function* to initialise an instance-specific property with it's own closure, when the instance is constructed. These types of actions can consume a bit of memory so don't store too much unique data.

```
function F() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.__init_increment(); // create `this.increment`
}
F.prototype.__init_increment = function () {
    var lastIncrementTime = -1;
    this.increment = function (time) {
        if (time > lastIncrementTime) {
            this.counter++;
            lastIncrementTime = time;
        }
        return this.counter;
    };
};
var f = new F();
f.increment(0); // 1
f.increment(0); // 1
f.increment(5); // 2
```

In this example, `this.increment` is a different *function* for each instance, which means you have a different closure for each instance. They are generated by a *function* in the *prototype*, which sets the instance property. The generator does not have to be in the prototype, just remember about the invocation context when applying it to your instance.

Comment: I want to have the instance specific counter. Kolink's version seems to be working just fine, I understand that in your case `this` will refer to the prototype object, which won't work for an instance specific counter, will it?

Comment: @MadEchet If you want something instance specific, you probably want it in the _constructor_ and not in the _prototype_. Kolink's solution "works" because you're using `caller` where you could just be using `this` normally, but that solution still has `lastIncrementTime` shared across all instances.

Comment: That's true, I did not realize that lastIncrementTime was shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Move your `var caller = this` inside the anonymous function, where `this` will have been set appropriately.

Comment: Or scratch the `var called` line, and just use `this` instead of `caller` within the returned function.

Comment: @Paul S. pointed out that a design problem in my code since `lastIncrementTime` is shared across variables, so I picked his answer.